# ASP.NET MVC : passing to view nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have the following model :

```
public class Business
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ....
    .....
    ....
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have the following function :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Business.ToListAsync());
}
```

and my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<ServiceProviderApp.Models.Business>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Business Engine";
}
.....
......
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
              ......
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
```

As you can understand, the Owner inside the Business is an Object. Therefore, when I try to access it in the view (item.Owner.Name) I don't get anything (null). I can change the query on the controller to return a record that is joined but then the model on the view won't be business any more.

I searched online but didn't find a good and clear explanation. Not sure why the EF doesn't bind the nested objects automatically.

One option that I saw on YouTube but I think that it sucks to do:

1. Create a new model with all the columns after the join
2. In my controller, run the join and pass it to the view
3. In the view accept the new model as parameter

Link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1B3R-kb9CU

Answer (score 1):

Solution : You need to use the include func in the controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var business = _context.Business.Include("Owner");
        return View(await business.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Thanks to DanielShabi for the help.